# Choosing Between One Component with a Property or Separate Components for Variations

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm currently developing a React library, and one of the components (let's call it `TableCell`) has multiple variations, such as `TextTableCell` and `NumberTableCell`. I'm in debate over whether to implement this as one versatile component with a property (e.g., `<TableCell type="number">{value}</TableCell>`) or as separate components (e.g., `<TextTableCell>{value}</TextTableCell>`).

My primary concern against using a single component with a property is that React may perform unnecessary evaluations on each render to determine how to render the `TableCell`. A counter-argument is that I could use a switch statement or an object to efficiently manage the rendering logic, such as:

```
<td>{formatters[props.type](props.value)}</td>
```

What's the best approach here, and what is your opinion on the matter? Are there potential performance issues I should consider, and what are the best practices in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React](https://react.dev/) is designed to be fast, and its [reconciliation algorithm](https://medium.com/javarevisited/react-reconciliation-algorithm-86e3e22c1b40) usually ensures efficient updates. If performance becomes a concern, you can optimize using [`React.memo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo), [`useMemo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo), or other optimization techniques.

But one of the best practices with React remains [SPR (Single Responsibility Principle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), where each component should do one thing well. That is illustrated by [many](https://dev.to/zahidhasan24/single-responsibility-principle-in-react-169i) [many](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-apply-solid-principles-to-clean-your-code-in-react-cdfd5e0a9cea) [different](https://www.octobot.io/blog/solid-principles-react/) [articles](https://medium.com/@roni.shabo/single-responsibility-in-reactjs-9c60e4163862).

That would be a strong argument for creating multiple specialized components, each responsible for one specific type of content rendering.

Check if your application is subject to interpretation and scaling. For example, if the different cell types share a lot of common characteristics in terms of structure, styling, or behavior, then one could argue that the "single responsibility" of the `TableCell` component is to render a cell based on a given type. In this case, the complexity of a versatile component might not violate SRP if its core responsibility remains singular in nature: rendering a table cell based on input properties.

So, whether a single versatile component or multiple specialized components better adhere to SRP depends on the level of abstraction you are focusing on:

- If the `TableCell` variations are similar enough, having a single component could fulfill SRP at a higher level of abstraction.
- On the other hand, if the variations require distinct logic, styles, or behaviors, then multiple components would align more closely with the principle.

---

> Could you please expand your answer with an example, of how an optimized version of this would look like?

You might consider an example where you have to display table cells that either contain text or numbers.

That way, we can illustrate how both approaches — a single versatile component and multiple specialized components — can be implemented in line with the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP):

#### Multiple Specialized Components Approach

In this strategy, you would have separate components for `TextTableCell` and `NumberTableCell`, each handling their own specific content rendering.

```
function TextTableCell({ children }) {
    return <td style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>{children}</td>;
}

function NumberTableCell({ children }) {
    return <td style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>{children}</td>;
}

// Usage
<TextTableCell>Sample text</TextTableCell>
<NumberTableCell>123</NumberTableCell>
```

##### SRP adherence:

- Each component has a single responsibility: rendering a table cell with text or number content, respectively, following specific styling rules.
- Easily maintainable and extendable. If you need to introduce a new variation, you can do so without modifying the existing components.

#### Single Versatile Component Approach

Here, a single `TableCell` component uses a `type` prop to determine how to render its content. That versatile component would include logic to handle different types of content appropriately.

```
function TableCell({ type, children }) {
    const style = { textAlign: type === 'number' ? 'right' : 'left' };
    return <td style={style}>{children}</td>;
}

// Usage
<TableCell type="text">Sample text</TableCell>
<TableCell type="number">123</TableCell>
```

##### SRP adherence:

- The component has a single responsibility: rendering a table cell based on the specified `type` prop.
- While this approach centralizes the logic for rendering different cell types, it does introduce a level of complexity, as the component must handle multiple rendering paths. However, it still adheres to the SRP, as it has one reason to change: modifications to how it renders table cells based on input properties.

#### Conclusion

Through these examples, you can observe how both approaches can respect the SRP while offering different levels of abstraction.

- The specialized components approach offers a more straightforward adherence to SRP, with each component doing one very specific thing, making them simpler and potentially easier to maintain.
- On the other hand, the single versatile component approach maintains adherence to SRP at a higher level of abstraction, leveraging a conditional to dictate the rendering style based on the type of content, thus centralizing the rendering logic in one place.

Your choice would depend on the complexity of the rendering logic and the potential future extensions of these components. It would be wise to anticipate the variations that might be needed in the future to choose the approach that will be most maintainable in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! If you have some time could you please expand your answer with an example, of how an optimized version of this would look like?

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs Sure. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Seriously, thank you so much!

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs No problem, glad to be of service. Let me know if anything is missing in this answer.